# Lightroom Crashes on Launch

Tags: lightroom

Hey everyone I have a weird bug Lightroom seems to crash every time I launch it except when I delete Lightroom 5 Preferences.agprefs after its removed Lightroom launches correctly every time. I have the latest version of Lightroom 5.3 installed. This is more of a question of has anyone elses encountered this bug? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: Apparently you fix this by deleting the preferences file... It's not uncommon for a pref file to become corrupted and crash an application. Just delete the file, set the preferences again to your liking and move one. If it crashes again quickly probably another problem is at play.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup program (online or NAS backup, for example) running, it can sometimes lock files that Lightroom needs to modify and cause a crash. I've seen this happen both when Lightroom starts and when it is exiting and trying to backup the catalogue file. I have reconfigured the backup program that I am using to not do backup of the Lightroom work file areas, this fixed the startup crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick search, there are more people that have ran into this problem. Here are some general troubleshooting steps you could have tried as well:

http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/Lightroom/h_more/troubleshooting.htm#6_-_Rename_the_Preferences_File

Removing the preferences file is one of the suggestions here. Apparently your Preferences file did get corrupted, somehow... Removing/renaming it, and starting Lightroom anew should resolve it. Unfortunately you will lose your preferences with this step, so be sure to regularly back-up your files!

J.

Answer (score 0):

Protip for the mac version run the Lightroom executable directly from the command line. For me this means running `/Applications/Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5` and exposed for me:

```
$ "/Applications/Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5"
<snip>
2014-11-19 19:08:10.535 Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5[87968:507] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-11-19 19:08:10.535 Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5[87968:507] AgPathUtils.getStandardFilePath: can't create directory at: /Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Lightroom
2014-11-19 19:08:10.535 Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5[87968:507] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85b0525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff87589e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85b04e09 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AgKernel                            0x000000010061c742 AgTransitQueue_enqueueToQueue + 3966
```

'lo and behold, when i checked out the file it was complaining about (at `Library/Application Support/Adobe/Lightroom`), it was a broken symlink created by Mackup. Goes to show me for using some fancy software that just "takes care of backups"... Removing that file fixed lightroom