# Lightroom 6 Single License Edition will not Load

Tags: lightroom-6

I purchased the Single Licence Lightroom 6 and I cannot get it to load past the initial splash screen it says " Windows encountered a problem and you have to close the program" this is very frustrating and I have not had a workable solution, I have re-installed a number of times and renamed the cache & store files to no avail. Its ridiculous after paying a reasonable sum for a product it will not function, Adobe has not covered itself in glory with this product, any help would be appreciated. I am using HP Notebook, 4gb ram and Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: This seems to be more of a Windows issue that has nothing to do with photography. Does Windows give a more detailed error code? Have you checked the WIndows error logs to see what they reveal?

Comment: Possibly related: [Lightroom Crashes on Launch](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48331/lightroom-crashes-on-launch). Also, this question might be a better fit on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a software application troubleshooting, not photography. Possibly better suited at [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

LR 6, although officially not supported to run under Windows 10 still seems to work for a lot of people without problems.

Please make sure you have installed the patches for **version 6.9** which you get here: https://community.adobe.com/t5/lightroom-classic-discussions/update-lightroom-to-6-9-standalone/m-p/8998750

The problem you describe went away for most people. If not, consider a clean new installation, followed by immediately patching the software.

If you experience lockups during work, please consider turning off GPU support and see if the problem persists.